# Laravel compare two query resultsets

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I want to get the difference between these two queries but it doesn't seem to work.

```
[
   {"subjectcodeco":"BIO 111","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"BIO 112","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"BIO 113","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"BIO 114","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"BIO 115","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"CHE 111","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"CHE 112","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"CHE 113","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"CHE 114","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"EDU 112","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"EDU 113","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"GSE 111","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"GSE 112","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"GSE 113","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
   {"subjectcodeco":"EDU 111","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"}
]
```

and this

```
[
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"BIO 111","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"BIO 112","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"BIO 113","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"BIO 114","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"BIO 115","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"CHE 111","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"CHE 112","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"CHE 113","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"CHE 114","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"EDU 111","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"EDU 112","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"EDU 113","subjectunitco":2,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"GSE 111","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"GSE 112","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"},
    {"matricno":"15\/1011","subjectcodeco":"GSE 113","subjectunitco":1,"subjectvalueco":"C"}
]
```

I've tried using laravel collection diffAssoc and diffKeys none of them seems to work.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: I'm expecting to get the 'subjectcodeco' in the first query that's not in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop your first set then compare the elements to the second:

```
$set1 = collect([...]); // Contents omitted for brevity
$set2 = collect([...]); // Contents omitted for brevity

$diff = [];

$set1->each(function($item, $key) {
    $exists = $set2->where(...)->first(); // Where clause omitted for brevity
    if($exists) {
        array_push($diff, $item);
    }
});

dd($diff); // Will contain the items of $set1 that don't exist in $set2
```

Comment: Hi, could you please be a little elaborate with the where clause?

Comment: You can check the documentation on how the `where` method of laravel collections works. [Check it here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where)

Comment: Noticed i needed to add use($set2, &$diff). This solved it for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption in your question is correct then you can do this.

```
foreach($query as $queries)
{
    foreach($secondQuery as $secondQueries)
    {
        if($queries['subjectcodeco'] == $secondQueries['subjectcodeco'])
        {
            //Condition Here
        }
        //And continue with the conditions
    }
}
```

Every iteration of every array value will also iterate all of the value inside of the second array, hence checking all the individual values of each array.